# Set background with databinding

Tags: c#, wpf

I got a list of Animals presented like that:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CvsAnimals}}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    </ListBox>
```

The presentation of each individual Animal is defined by a DataTemplate. The template should set the color of the background of each Animal:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Animal}">
    <Border>
        <Border.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Health, Converter={StaticResource HealthToColor}}" />
        </Border.Background>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding VisualId}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

Animal:

```
public enum HealthStatus
{
    Ok,
    Warning,
    Sick,
    Unknown
}

partial class Animal :  ObservableObject
{
    private HealthStatus _health = HealthStatus.Unknown;

    public HealthStatus Health
    {
      get {return _health; }
      set {  Set(() => Health, ref _health, value); }
    }
}
```

I expected the background color of each Animal to be set according to the property `Health` of each element. But the setting of the background color is not working. Why?

Here's part of my color converter:

```
public class HealthColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly SolidColorBrush ColorSick = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    private static readonly SolidColorBrush ColorHealthy = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LimeGreen);
    private static readonly SolidColorBrush ColorWarning = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is HealthStatus)
        {
            var health = (HealthStatus)value;

            switch (health)
            {
                case HealthStatus.Ok:
                    return ColorHealthy;
                case HealthStatus.Sick:
                    return ColorSick;
                case HealthStatus.Warning:
                    return ColorWarning;
                default:
                    return ColorSick;
                    //return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
```

Comment: I've had similar problem, just call `ToString()` on your Color and you're sorted :-), i.e. Colors.Red.ToString();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your converter converts health to `SolidColorBrush`, so it should be like this:

```
<Border Background="{Binding Health, Converter={StaticResource HealthToColor}}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding VisualId}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

If you keep the XAML code unchanged, you need to modify the converter to return `Color`:

```
public class HealthColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
  private static readonly Color ColorSick = Colors.Red;
  private static readonly Color ColorHealthy = Colors.LimeGreen;
  private static readonly SolidColorBrush ColorWarning = Colors.Yellow;

  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    if (value is HealthStatus)
    {
        var health = (HealthStatus)value;

        switch (health)
        {
            case HealthStatus.Ok:
                return ColorHealthy;
            case HealthStatus.Sick:
                return ColorSick;
            case HealthStatus.Warning:
                return ColorWarning;
            default:
                return ColorSick;
                //return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        }
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: Feeling a little silly right now. You are right! Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nabulke you're welcome, it also occurred to me sometimes in the beginning time of learning WPF.